# After the user delete his account and again create a new account the App got crash Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

First of all the user starts creating a new account:

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        ....

                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, loginActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        RegisterActivity.this.finish();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered ok!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

As we can see after the user is registered I'm sending it to the `loginActivity.class`. Ok here in loginActivity.class the user start login:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("password", password);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
...
}
```

Again, if the login is isSuccessful I'm sending the user to the `MainActivity.class`. I'm saving the password to after delete his account. Now the user delete his account, this happen in `MainActivity.class`:

```
 btnDeleteAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(user.getEmail(), password);
                // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
                user.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                           // mAuth.signOut();
                                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, loginActivity.class);
                                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                            startActivity(intent);

                                        }else{
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't delete: "+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                    }
                });
```

As we can see, After of re-authenticate the user I'm sending the user to `loginActivity.class`. Ok now the user decide create a new account again. Then `RegisterActivity.class`:

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
              
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        mProgressBar.dismiss();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, loginActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        RegisterActivity.this.finish();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered ok!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "can't register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

now, the app got crash! this error happens inside `MainActivity.class` I don't know why here, if I'm sending the user to `loginActivity.class` after his registration.. why happen this.. this is the error:

```
2020-10-19 15:23:55.096 13177-13177/com.example.registration E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.registration, PID: 13177
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.registration/com.example.registration.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6253)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.registration.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6667)
```

this says that `com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference` this is because I'm getting that value inside my `MainActivity.class`

```
  userEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
    userID.setText(user.getUid());
```

I don't know why this happens inside MainActivity. When the user make his registration I'm doing this   `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` at the first time works, but when the user delete his account and again create a new account this throw an error.

In the `loginActivity.class` I'm controlling the user state:

```
 mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

                        Intent intentMainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        intentMainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intentMainActivity);

                    }
                }

            }
        };
```

And also inside of `MainActivity.class`

```
mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                        Intent intentLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), loginActivity.class);
                    intentLogin.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intentLogin);
                }

            }
        };
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: "I'm saving the password to after delete his account." Depending on how you implemented this, this may open up your users to a security risk. If the Firebase API requires that your user signs in again, you should ask them to re-enter their credentials.

Comment: Aside from that, it seems that `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` in your code returns `null`, which means that no user is signed in at that point. You'll need to handle this condition in your code, any time you call `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` as the user may get signed out at any moment.

Comment: I will ask to my users for his credentials in fact. When an user is registered, after  goes to `loginActivity` and on there the `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener` says that the user is != null. My trick to force to Log In the user was save a `keyvalue` inside the `SharedPreferences`. Now when the user delete his account that `keyvalue` is deleted from the `SharedPreferences`. When the user create a new account again it will be redirectly to `loginActivity` and inside of AuthStateListener of this class there is a condition. `if (!keyvalue.isEmpty())`then redirect to MainActivity.

Comment: The `keyvalue` is saved when the user makes `Log In`. Therefore if the user delete his account this value will be deleted as well. Thanks to the condition in the `loginActivity` and inside of `AuthStateListener` I check for this value if it is not isEmpty then redirect to `MainActivity`. If I not use that condition, when the user creates a new account it will be redirectly to `MainActivity` instantly because `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener` is pending of the user checking if this is != null. In spite of make `SignOut` after the registration the userId is not null.